# Kubernetes reattach to same persistent volume after delete

Tags: kubernetes

I have a app where two pods needs to have access to the same volume. I want to be able to delete the cluster and then after apply to be able to access the data that is on the volume.

So for example:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: retaining
provisioner: csi.hetzner.cloud
reclaimPolicy: Retain
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer 

---

kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: media
spec:
  #storageClassName: retaining
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp-php
  labels:
    app: myapp-php
    k8s-app: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp-php
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp-php
        k8s-app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx:1.17
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: myapp-php
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 750m
            memory: 3Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 750m
            memory: 3Gi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: media
          mountPath: /var/www/html/media
      volumes:
      - name: media
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: media
      nodeSelector:
        mytype: main

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp-web
  labels:
    app: myapp-web
    k8s-app: myapp
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp-web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp-web
        k8s-app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx:1.17
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: myapp-web
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 128Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 128Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: media
          mountPath: /var/www/html/media
      volumes:
      - name: media
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: media
      nodeSelector:
        mytype: main
```

If I do these:

```
k apply -f pv-issue.yaml 
k delete -f pv-issue.yaml 
k apply-f pv-issue.yaml
```

I want to connect the same volume.

What I have tried:

1. If I keep the file as is, the volume will be deleted so the data will be lost.
2. I can remove the pvc declaration from the file. Then it works. My issue that on the real app I am using kustomize and I don't see a way to exclude resources when doing `kustomize build app | kubectl delete -f -`
3. Tried using retain in the pvc. It retains the volume on delete, but on the apply a new volume is created.
4. Statefulset, however I don't see a way that to different statefulsets can share the same volume.

Is there a way to achieve this?
Or should I just do regular backups, and restore the volume data from backup when recreating the cluster?

Comment: Yeah, if you want to keep the volume even after recreating the cluster, then the data must be located outside the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

**Is there a way to achieve this? Or should I just do regular backups, and restore the volume data from backup when recreating the cluster?**

Cluster deletion will make all your local volumes to be deleted. You can achieve this by storing the data outside the cluster. `Kubernetes`  has a wide variety of storage providers to help you deploy data on a variety of storage types.

You may want to think also that you can keep the data locally on nodes with usage of `hostPath` but that is also not a good solution since it will require you to pin the pod to the specific  node to avoid data loss. And if you delete you cluster in a way that all of you `VM` are gone, then this will be also gone.

Having some network-attached storage would be right way to go here. Very good example of those are [Persistence disks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#pdspecs) which durable network storage devices that you instances can access. They're located independently from you virtuals machines and they [are not being deleted](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/deleting-a-cluster) when you delete the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't help much but notice that you have all in one yaml file. Seperate the PVC into its own yaml file and you will see you will reattach to the same PV. I know it sounds kinda dumb but try it you'll see.

The issue is you are deleting the PVC which then releases its hold on the PV, the PV is now in released status basically in limbo. The next time you run your file the PVC will create a new PV. Now you have two PV's :(sad). you need to do something like this

```
https://medium.com/building-the-open-data-stack/reclaiming-persistent-volumes-in-kubernetes-5e035ba8c770
```

Or like I mentioned earlier you can put the PVC in its own yaml file but you will still have the same problem if you ever run a delete on that PVC yaml file.

I am dealing with this for a single deployment of 5.7 MySQL. My Longhorn storage class is set to retain.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible at least on vsphere VMDK.

Set PV to retain so VMDK is not lost when PV/PVC is deleted. Backup PVC/PV, strip the yamls from dynamic annotation and claim.ref.UID and resource version.

Rebuild the cluster and reapply first PV and then PVC. Both should be bound and VMDK still present on datastore.

After that you can attach to the volume again with existing data.

I have migrated multiple PROD OCP clusters like that with reattaching the data.

Confluent is upgrading their kubernetes clusters as well like that. Why backup and restore, when you can just reattach to the same data.